# Should design documents be organized based on data model?

Tags: couchdb

In `CouchDB`, should `design documents` be made for each "data entity", or model, that is being stored in the database? Or, should there be one design document that encompasses views for all of your needed views?

For example, if I have some `Users` and `Comments` in the database, would I have a single design document possibly called `_design/blog` and in it I'd have views named like `usersByName`, or `commentsByDate`, etc.

Or, should I have seperate design documents, like `_design/users`, `_design/comments`, in which I have views named like `byName`, or `byDate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a good question.A design document by itself is just a collection of views ,list , show,update functions.All of the work of your "application layer" will be performed by these functions.So I feel that rather than having a different design document for each of of your entities the separation should be made on these functions.The blogging scenario that you have outlined in the question is a great example of how design documents should be used.

Think of design documents as the file structure of your application.If you were building applications using some other framework you would probably have only one file structure for your application.By the way there is nothing stopping you from creating more than one design document in the application.But I feel that it gets a little unmanageable this way.

Just to recap

**One design document per application with separate view,show functions if needed.**